# How do I enable permissions to FormApp?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a Google Apps script in which I want to use the `FormApp` service to get the active form, however it keeps throwing an exception:

```
You do not have permission to call FormApp.getActiveForm. Required permissions:
(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.currentonly ||
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms) (line 7, file "Code")
```

I have enabled permissions to both Google Drive API, and to Google Sheets API - but can't find an API labeled as "Forms" anywhere in the Google Cloud Platform API Dashboard.

Googling has not turned up anything useful, just more links to the API documentation.

Any idea which API FormApp is classified under?

I don't want to have to enable every single API to find out...

Comment: There is no API for Google Forms.  So, you don't need to enable anything in the Cloud Platform.  You either need to run the code from the code editor to force a new authorization prompt, or if you are setting scopes manually in the appsscript.json file, you need to add a scope.

Comment: You don't need to activate any api.  1. When it first runs, it'll ask for authorization, Did you accept? 2. Did you modify `appsscript.json` file?

Comment: Ah I did not know that. I added the scopes manually and that fixed it. Will update with an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For future people who come across this post, I resolved my issue by manually adding the following to my Manifest file:

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
],
```

You can find your Manifest file by clicking on `View > Show Manifest File` - this will make a file called `appscript.json` appear in your sidebar.

Then click `Run` or the play button in the toolbar - which will force the app to review permissions and prompt you to authorize with your account.

**Note:** A good point that @tehhowch has pointed out below is that adding this manually to your manifest will disable auto-detection of scopes. My auto-detection doesn't seem to be working correctly anyway, so I've gone ahead with this manual solution - just a word of warning.

Comment: Note that specifying any OAuth scopes manually disables automatic scope detection. Any new scopes you need will similarly need to be added manually once you specify any manual scopes.

Comment: How about putting the comment of ``// FormApp.getActiveForm()`` in your script? By this, the scope of ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms`` is added by the automatic detection of the script editor. In this case, the automatic detection of the script editor is not disabled.

Comment: @Tanaike hmm I tried that in a brand new project - but it does not seem to work for me as you describe... not sure why

Comment: @Vidur I'm really sorry my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: No worries. Not a problem. Have already wrapped up the project that I needed the code for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. just now you can find the Manifest file by clicking on 'Project setting' tab on the left pane and make sure to check 'Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor'. and it will be shown at 'Files' in 'Editor' tab.

Answer (score 4):

Put

```
FormApp.getActiveForm();
```

in the first line of your function you're calling and manually call that function from editor. It asks you for permissions before it realises you're calling it from the editor.